# ¿Cómo deshabilitar un reporte apex oracle?

Tags: oracle, apex

Tengo un reporte de oracle mediante apex al cual acceden algunos usuarios mediante un link, pero no quiero borrarlo solo quiero deshabilitarlo, osea que aunque ingresen el link no les muestre nada como si el reporte no existiera.

Acceden al reporte a una ruta como esta:

```
http://xx.xx.x.xx:8080/apex/f?p=107:4:3434397151647::NO
```

[image: Estas son todas las opciones que tiene]

Answer (score 0):

Cuál es la versión de tu APEX?
En la versión actual debes seleccionar el reporte y buscar la opción Server-side Condition y esa cambiarle el valor a Never. Creo que en la versión que tienes la opción debe llamarse algo relacionado con Conditional. Saludos!